# Is it possible to add multiple condition to a if/else Conditional (ternary) operator?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements, conditional-operator

actually i want to add some extra condition to a Conditional (ternary) operator
by targeting the first character of a each arrays' item if it equal to vowel character type 'an' otherwise type 'a'.is it possible to do this in a one-line statement?

```
const containerEl = document.querySelector(".container");

const careers = \[
"Youtuber",
"Web Desigenr",
"Frontend",
"Astronaut",
"Geek",
"armrester",
\];

let careersIndex = 0;
let charInedx = 0;

updateText();

function updateText() {
charInedx++;
containerEl.innerHTML = \`\<h1\>I am

${**(careers\[careersIndex\].slice(0,1) === "a" ? "an" : "a")**}

${careers\[careersIndex\].slice(0, charInedx)}\</h1\>\`;

if (charInedx === careers\[careersIndex\].length) {
careersIndex++;
charInedx = 0;
}
if (careersIndex === careers.length) {
careersIndex = 0;
}
setTimeout(updateText, 300);
}
```

my current statement like this but doesn't work:

`(careers[careersIndex].slice(0,1) === 'a' || 'A' || 'e' || 'i' || 'I' ? 'an' : 'a'))`

Comment: Yes, need to enclose all the conditions within scope brackets that comes before ternary operator `(cond1 || cond2 || cond 3) ? ... : ...;`

Comment: If you need to check a character is from a set of characters `"aAeEiIoOuU".includes((careers[careersIndex].slice(0,1)) ? ... : ...;`